# My Java Spring Boot application adds the suffix '_seq' to table users

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

On execution of my spring boot application with MySQL as data source, it fails with below error message

> `Table 'schema.users_seq' doesn't exist`

I have an **@Entity class Users** with an **AUTO_INC field** *Id*

```
@Entity
    @Table(appliesTo = "users")
    public class Users {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="uid")
    private long id;
    }
```

## Below is my User controller class

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/cm/api/user")
    public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;
    @GetMapping("/{username}")
    public void getUser(@PathVariable("username") String userName) {
    }
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public void addNewUser(@RequestBody Users users) {
    usersRepository.save(users);
    }
   }
```

There are some other articles on the same issue, but it all ended with the question if the class has AUTO_INC field.

Answer (score 3):

Your app tries to generate a `long` ID for your `Users` entity by retrieving a value from the `users_seq`. You need to change the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` according to your DDL structure. As you didn't include that in your post, I can only assume how you mapped it, so I can only recommend that you read [this article by Hibernate maintainer Vlad Mihalcea about why you should not use the AUTO JPA GenerationType with MySQL and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to have auto increment IDs only probably you should consider using `GenerationType.IDENTITY`

Secondly, on why you are getting error:

Assuming in your DDL `private long id` you have an AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, when using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` in the Entity class, Spring data JPA would pick `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` as per this [documentation](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc#implicit-identifier-sequence-and-table-name). That is why you are getting this error:

> Table 'schema.users_seq' doesn't exist

To solve this you need to create a table in your DB to have the sequence IDs

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schema`.`users_seq` (
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `next_val` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`))
```

Taken from here on [how to create a custom SequenceGenerator](https://www.truiton.com/2024/02/spring-boot-hibernate-jpa-generationtype-table-vs-sequence-strategy-with-mysql/#Custom-SequenceGenerator)